# How can I Identify which condition satisfied the if statement?

Tags: programming-logic, logic

Suppose, I am using a if statement as such:

```
if(A || B || C || D)
{

   echo "Hurrah! if is satisfied!";
   echo "But! How can I know which was true of the 4 (A,B,C,D)";

}
```

Is there any way I can know which condition(s) among A,B,C,D were true?

Comment: Test it one by one, in the same order ?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: If you need to do something in each case anyway, it would be simpler to simply have `if(A) { ... } if (B) { ...} ...`.  If you need something to be performed if you entered one of these if clauses, set a boolean to true and after you've done operations for A, B, C, and D, add a fifth block for the case in which your boolean is true.

Comment: No, you can't. Masking the difference between these different cases is the precise *purpose* of the OR operator. You can only find out about A, B C a D individually by stepping through your program and stopping *before* the `||` executes.

Comment: Print A, B, C and D and you'll know which ones are true.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be something like a homework question.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there's a simple statement that you're probably familiar with:

```
if(A || B || C || D)
{

   echo "Hurrah! if is satisfied!";
   echo "But! How can I know which was true of the 4 (A,B,C,D)";

   if (A)
      echo "A was true";

   if (B) /* NOT else if */
      echo "B was true";
}
```

There's no way to unscramble an egg. You can't get `A` back from `A||B||C||D`.

Answer (score 1):

You kinda can....

Assuming each of A, B, C and D are either 0 or 1:

```
result = A + 2*B + 4*C + 8*D;
if (result) {
   echo "Hurrah! if is satisfied!";

   // you can now check different bits of your result
}
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that your test is data-type dependent.  If A is more than a single bit, or a string or an object, it won't work.